# R variable list for lapply results in error: "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Tags: r

I'm trying to do something really trivial but I'm running into a wall. I want a vector which stores the means of some variables.

I tried:

```
vars <- c("eins_d$q05a", "eins_d$q05b", "eins_d$q05c", "eins_d$q05d", "eins_d$q05e", "eins_d$q05f", "eins_d$q05g", "eins_d$q05h", "eins_d$q05i", "eins_d$q05j")
means <- lapply(vars, mean)
```

I also tried:

```
means <- numeric()
for (var in c("eins_d$q05a", "eins_d$q05b", "eins_d$q05c", "eins_d$q05d", "eins_d$q05e", "eins_d$q05f", "eins_d$q05g", "eins_d$q05h", "eins_d$q05i", "eins_d$q05j")) {
        means <- append(means, mean(var))
}
```

In both cases it does not recognise that I want the operation done using the variables but rather it takes the argument as a string and then complains that the argument is not numeric.

However if I do the same but instead of giving the name explicitly I define the list using:

```
vars <- names(eins_d[5:15])
```

it works as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `lapply(eins_d[5:15], mean)`

Comment: You are applying the mean in your vector `vars` which is a character vector, hence the `NA`s. There is a difference between `lapply(vars, mean)` and `lappy(eins_d[vars], mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see clearly what happens, consider that I want the mean of `var1` and `var2` only from following data frame,

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = 2:6, var3 = 3:7)

#  var1 var2 var3
#1    1    2    3
#2    2    3    4
#3    3    4    5
#4    4    5    6
#5    5    6    7

#so our vars will be,
vars <- c('var1', 'var2')

lapply(vars, mean) #--> Tries to find the mean of the strings 'var1' and 'var2'
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#whereas,

lapply(df[vars], mean) #--> Tries to find the mean of columns 'var1' and 'var2' from 'df'
#$var1
#[1] 3

#$var2
#[1] 4
```

Comment: thank you, it's clear now for the lapply (which is the preferred method anyway)
But why did it also not work in the for-loop?

Comment: @RichardBoonen For exactly the same reason.